# How to create/delete files in secondary storage SDCARD version after KitKat?

Tags: android, saf

Knows that the permission of creating and deleting changes to SAF(storage access framework) in secondary storage SDCARD OS version after KitKat.

Under manifests, permission has been set,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Version after KitKat
By using new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
Secondary storage SDCARD route will be chosen, converting DocumentUri
set as takePersistableUriPermission()

For example, Version before KitKat.

```
File file = new File(path);
file.delete()
```

can be successfully deleted.

version after KitKat,
delete() getting write permission error,

```
DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file)));
```

using deleteDocument() not found indicated with documented and unable to delete.

Is there any solutions for this issue?
Is there any ways to find/change General mediated or filed to documented?

Comment: I am facing same problem. Any solution?